How do I install Ubuntu 20.04 after the installation failed?
I tried to download and install Ubuntu 20.04. I got stuff I don't understand when I tried to boot. How do I try again?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please Edit your question to include the error messages you encountered. Also read How do I ask a good question? And provide us more details.

any reason not to go for 24.04? "I got stuff I don't understand when I tried to boot"  Please be specific.

Consider reviewing the installation guides available on this site. Also, consider trying Ubuntu 24.04
